# Android: Adding navigation drawer gives run time errors

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, navigation-drawer

So I need to add a navigation drawer to my main activity and for doing so I used this tutorial http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android. I modified the xmls and added the code to my main activity. The tutorial code works properly independently but when I integrate it with my main activity it gives the following logcat messages.

This is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private AppAdapter listadapter = null;

    public boolean[] status = { true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mTitle = "test";

        mPlanetTitles = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
        ) {
            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        ActionBarActivity obj = new ActionBarActivity();

        obj.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        obj.getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            status = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray("status");
        }

        OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lv, View item, int position, long id) {

                ListView lView = (ListView) lv;
                SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) lView.getAdapter();
                HashMap<String,Object> hm = (HashMap) adapter.getItem(position);
                /** The clicked Item in the ListView */
                RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) item;
                /** Getting the toggle button corresponding to the clicked item */
                ToggleButton tgl = (ToggleButton) rLayout.getChildAt(1);

                String strStatus = "";
                if(tgl.isChecked()){
                    tgl.setChecked(false);
                    strStatus = "Off";
                    status[position]=false;
                }else{
                    tgl.setChecked(true);
                    strStatus = "On";
                    status[position]=true;
                }
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), (String) hm.get("txt") + " : " + strStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        new LoadApplications().execute();
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBooleanArray("status", status);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);

        try{
            Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

            if(intent != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {

        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> appList = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();

        for(ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try{
                if(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName) != null) {
                    appList.add(info);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return appList;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

            listadapter = new AppAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadapter);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "Loading apps info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Swaps fragments in the main content view
     */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        ActionBarActivity obj = new ActionBarActivity();
        obj.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.listofapps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Example" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the main activity.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ListView 
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Can someone please give me a hint or guide me. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Could you locate which line throwed NPE? your logcat trace is not complete, I think

Comment: What is this ActionBarActivity obj = new ActionBarActivity();? you cant use something like this. And post full logcat by copying the text not the image.

Comment: @Harry +1 Thanks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. I am actually new to Android and was using objects to access functions of other classes. The line where I create the object obj and use it later is actually the error as pointed out by [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3692327/harry). Once I removed that I just needed to change getSupportActionBar to getActionBar and I was done. Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the `MainActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.
Like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    ...
    >
</activity>
```

Your logcat trace implies that the `Activity` can't be found through the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, but I cannot understand exactly what you mean. I think I have done it the way you have asked to.

Comment: @SilentKinght No, I didn't :(